# python 3d list assign and index different result

Tags: python, list

[image]

When I assign to an element in 3d python list, it will change 3 element.

Does anyone know what happened?

Comment: When you say [[[0,0]]*4], that doesn't create a list referring to four different lists.  That creates a list containing 4 references to a SINGLE list.  There is one [0,0] list object,  The easiest way to do what you want doing is to use `numpy`.  Short of that, you'll need to use nested loops.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I should go deeper to python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, It has to do with the underlying way in which arrays are stored in Python. When you created your array initially, with the [[0,0]]*4, you created four pointers to the same list(you did that four separate times, hence why 1/4 of your lists were changed). Thus, when you change 1 value, it changes it in that one list, but there are multiple pointers to the same list, so it appears to change multiple values. I highly recommend http://pythontutor.com/ for visualizing how your code is executed/the underlying structures at play.